# Trying to use certbox to get SSL Certificate, however command sudo certbot --apache failed on ec2 instance

Tags: apache, amazon-ec2, ssl-certificate, lets-encrypt, certbot

[Here are the instructions I was following](https://certbot.eff.org/lets-encrypt/ubuntuxenial-apache), and here is the error I'm receiving when I attempt to run `sudo certbot --apache`

I am ssh'd into my EC2 instance and successfully ran all of the commands in section 2 and 3 of the instructions, but now this command in 4 is failing. Here is the output:

```
bitnami@ip-172-31-82-209:~/apps/InterSportsGraphs$ sudo certbot --apache
Saving debug log to /var/log/letsencrypt/letsencrypt.log
Plugins selected: Authenticator apache, Installer apache
Starting new HTTPS connection (1): acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org
No names were found in your configuration files. Please enter in your domain
name(s) (comma and/or space separated)  (Enter 'c' to cancel): bigleaguegraphs.com www.bigleaguegraphs.com
Obtaining a new certificate
Performing the following challenges:
http-01 challenge for bigleaguegraphs.com
http-01 challenge for www.bigleaguegraphs.com
Enabled Apache rewrite module
Error while running apache2ctl graceful.
httpd not running, trying to start
Action 'graceful' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information.

AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.0.1. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
(98)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:80
(98)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80
no listening sockets available, shutting down
AH00015: Unable to open logs

Unable to restart apache using ['apache2ctl', 'graceful']
Cleaning up challenges
Error while running apache2ctl graceful.
httpd not running, trying to start
Action 'graceful' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information.

AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.0.1. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
(98)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:80
(98)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80
no listening sockets available, shutting down
AH00015: Unable to open logs

Unable to restart apache using ['apache2ctl', 'graceful']
Encountered exception during recovery: 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/certbot_apache/configurator.py", line 2185, in _reload
    util.run_script(self.option("restart_cmd"))
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/certbot/util.py", line 86, in run_script
    raise errors.SubprocessError(msg)
certbot.errors.SubprocessError: Error while running apache2ctl graceful.
httpd not running, trying to start
Action 'graceful' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information.

AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.0.1. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
(98)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:80
(98)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80
no listening sockets available, shutting down
AH00015: Unable to open logs


During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/certbot/auth_handler.py", line 75, in handle_authorizations
    resp = self._solve_challenges(aauthzrs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/certbot/auth_handler.py", line 139, in _solve_challenges
    resp = self.auth.perform(all_achalls)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/certbot_apache/configurator.py", line 2287, in perform
    self.restart()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/certbot_apache/configurator.py", line 2175, in restart
    self._reload()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/certbot_apache/configurator.py", line 2203, in _reload
    raise errors.MisconfigurationError(error)
certbot.errors.MisconfigurationError: Error while running apache2ctl graceful.
httpd not running, trying to start
Action 'graceful' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information.

AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.0.1. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
(98)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:80
(98)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80
no listening sockets available, shutting down
AH00015: Unable to open logs


During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/certbot_apache/configurator.py", line 2185, in _reload
    util.run_script(self.option("restart_cmd"))
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/certbot/util.py", line 86, in run_script
    raise errors.SubprocessError(msg)
certbot.errors.SubprocessError: Error while running apache2ctl graceful.
httpd not running, trying to start
Action 'graceful' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information.

AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.0.1. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
(98)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:80
(98)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80
no listening sockets available, shutting down
AH00015: Unable to open logs


During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/certbot/error_handler.py", line 108, in _call_registered
    self.funcs[-1]()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/certbot/auth_handler.py", line 323, in _cleanup_challenges
    self.auth.cleanup(achalls)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/certbot_apache/configurator.py", line 2312, in cleanup
    self.restart()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/certbot_apache/configurator.py", line 2175, in restart
    self._reload()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/certbot_apache/configurator.py", line 2203, in _reload
    raise errors.MisconfigurationError(error)
certbot.errors.MisconfigurationError: Error while running apache2ctl graceful.
httpd not running, trying to start
Action 'graceful' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information.

AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.0.1. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
(98)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:80
(98)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80
no listening sockets available, shutting down
AH00015: Unable to open logs

Error while running apache2ctl graceful.
httpd not running, trying to start
Action 'graceful' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information.

AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.0.1. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
(98)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:80
(98)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80
no listening sockets available, shutting down
AH00015: Unable to open logs
```

The meat of the error message, which appears throughout this error, I think is the following:

```
AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.0.1. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
(98)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:80
(98)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80
```

Any direction as to how I can debug this in order to get the SSL Certificate for my website would be great, thanks! I am not a networking person but need to get this done to secure my website. Please let me know if I can share any addt'l info that will help with this, or how I should go about resolving this in general. Thanks!

Edit: I used https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/ to test my domain bigleaguegraphs.com but don't quite understand the output here either.

Edit2: Here are two links to other posts:

- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/381646/aws-ec2-instance-says-apache2-isnt-running-but-the-server-is-still-up-and-httpd
- https://community.bitnami.com/t/i-unable-to-restart-apache/47636

...that seem like they could be related to my post?

Comment: You are trying to run certbot with the `--apache` flag but apache is not able to run on the machine (the reason being the last log output as you already figured). This makes me wonder, when apache can't run your website cannot be online as well? The `--apache` flag is meant for a use case where an apache server serves your websites to the outside world. However it seems your website is served by something else maybe from another place, what/where is this?

Comment: Thanks @JeyDWork - I deploy my website using `forever`. Pretty much the only commands I run on the ec2 instance (besides `cd`) are `sudo forever stopall` to stop the website, `git pull` to grab the latest code for the website, then I install new packages on the ec2 instance if needed, then `sudo NODE_ENV=prod forever start index.js` to redeploy the website.

Comment: alright, so it is served by node.js not apache. Meaning you are on the whole wrong track with `certbot --apache`. You probably could make apache work just to get the cert with apache but it would be a hassle and then you will still need to integrate the cert in node.js (depending on what you use here probably express.js). So I'd recommend another certbot approach. Either DNS based (see https://certbot.eff.org/docs/using.html#dns-plugins) or something which directly works with node.js/express.js (first Google hit: https://www.sitepoint.com/how-to-use-ssltls-with-node-js/).

Comment: @JeyDWork combine all of this into an answer instead of a comment and I'll give you the bounty. Incredibly helpful stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your posted log output and comments we know that your website is served by node.js and not Apache.
This means you are left with three choices:

1. Get Apache to work just to get the Let's Encrypt certificate. I wouldn't recommend this approach because it will be troublesome. Apache would conflict with node.js regarding used ports and when you solved that you would still need to integrate the retrieved certificate in node.js.
2. Instead of retrieving the certificate with Apache and the `--apache` flag you can directly retrieve it through certbot and any other server like for example node.js. Typically this will involve using certbot with the `certonly --webroot` option and you will need to modify your node.js server (just a little bit) to actually use the retrieved certificate and listen on an additional port for SSL/TLS connections. A good starting point for this approach may be this article which is for node.js and express.js (and express.js is the package which is by far the most popular HTTP server package for node.js so it is very likely your website uses it as well or at least a very similar package): https://www.sitepoint.com/how-to-use-ssltls-with-node-js/ 
   This is the approach I would recommend if you have one site or a small number of sites for which you would like to get certificates.
3. Instead of letting Let's Encrypt verify your website via HTTP, which always involves serving the challenge responses via an existing server (like Apache and with with the `--apache` flag) or any other server (with the `certonly --webroot` option) you also can serve these responses via DNS. This also works with the `certonly` option (and you also will need to modify node.js to actually use the certificate like in previous approaches) but it is a little bit more complicated with additional required options wich may vary depending on your DNS provider. You can find an overview of documentations for popular DNS providers at https://certbot.eff.org/docs/using.html#dns-plugins. 
   This is the approach I'd absolutely recommend if you have somewhat more websites and if you want wildcard certificates (pro tip: there are ready to use docker images for each DNS provider: https://hub.docker.com/r/certbot/certbot/).

Comment: Thank you. I will reply with further detail when I attempt to implement what you've suggested. Didn't assign bounty before expire so I created a new one and will assign when it allows me!

Comment: Let me know when you choose a specific approach and have further questions. Currently it's hard to answer in more detail since there would be a lot of possibilities for each approach and there are still some unknown facts. If you go for 2 or 3 like I would recommend you might come across questions how to integrate the certificate. Therefore we will need to know if your current node.js website uses express.js. Look for `require('express')`. If it's not there your project doesn't use it, look for `require('http')` in that case. Those will probably indicate the location to integrate the cert.